# Is it possible to get all big_map keys using node RPC?

Tags: rpc, bigmap

Granada changelog mentions:

> Added a new RPC to retrieve several Big Map values at once: `/chains/<chain_id>/blocks/<block_id>/context/big_maps/<big_map_id>?offset=<int>&length=<int>`

AFAIU it returns only values, but not keys, is that correct? I tried testing my assumption, here's what I've found:

1. `tezos-client rpc get 'chains/main/blocks/head/context/big_maps/2'` prints `[ { "int": "100" } ]` while https://better-call.dev/granadanet/big_map/2/keys says "Nothing found".
2. `tezos-client rpc get 'chains/main/blocks/head/context/big_maps/1009'` prints `[]` while https://better-call.dev/granadanet/big_map/1009/keys finds a couple of items.

So I was unable to test it in a way I would be able to comprehend. Does anyone know if there is API to return all big_map **keys** without using any external indexer?

Answer (score 1):

Big map keys are not stored so a tezos-node has no way to provide them.